# GWT Bootstrap Responsive Design of existing webapp with screens

Tags: java, css, twitter-bootstrap, gwt, gwt-bootstrap

I have a working web application developed with GWT. Now that it has to resize on a tablet or smaller screens I thought of using GWT Bootstrap. But the existing application has only one project.html and project.css file under war folder. Currently no UI binders are used. There are four screens displaying different charts created by d3js.

My Question is it still possible to use gwt bootstrap for resizing? Or what about only Bootstrap and use the css file without any UI binders?

Which approach is better ? As im confused and have spent couple of hours searching and reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you plan to interact in your `GWT` app with bootstrap components (i.e. `NavBar`, `Caoursel`, etc) then I would go with `gwt-bootstrap` because you don't have to use `JSNI` and you get some type safety.

If you don't need to interact those components or you use mostly pure `HTML` in your GWT app you can also use plain `bootstrap` and add the corresponding classes.

Edit code example:

UiBinder:

```
<b:NavPills>
  <b:AnchorListItem active="true">Item 1</b:AnchorListItem>
  <b:AnchorListItem>Item 2</b:AnchorListItem>
  <b:AnchorListItem>Item 3</b:AnchorListItem>
  <b:AnchorListItem enabled="false">Item 4</b:AnchorListItem>
  <b:AnchorListItem pull="RIGHT">Pulled right</b:AnchorListItem>
</b:NavPills>
```

Code:

```
NavPills pills = new NavPills();
AnchorListItem item1 = new AnchorListItem("Item 1");
item1.setActive(true);
pills.add(item1);
pills.add(new AnchorListItem("Item 2");
pills.add(new AnchorListItem("Item 3");
...
```

Comment: Can I use gwt bootstrap and not use any UI Binders. Because currently I dont use UI Binder for the UI widgets. Everything is defined in the code in java. I hope you understand what I mean by java code.

Comment: Sure Ui Binder is only a declerative approach of java code

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. So I just use <inherits name="org.gwtbootstrap3.GwtBootstrap3"/> in the *.gwt.xml file then setstyle in java is it?

Comment: Yes or you use the bootsrap's gwt widgets

Comment: could you please tell me how to use bootsrap's gwt widgets by editing the answer. Then I will mark this answer.